# System services not available to Activities before onCreate() while opening a Dialog from RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm having this error out of the blue and have no idea what's causing it or where it has come from.

Basically I've got a `RecyclerView` that gets populated with products. When a product is selected, I've got a custom `Dialog` that pops up where the user can increase product quantity or remove the product. This all works, however if I click the same product a second time it crashes the app with the following error:

> System services not available to Activities before `onCreate()`

This is my `RecyclerView.Adapter` with the `onBindViewHolder()`

```
public class OrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Item Item = ItemList.get(position);


        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.Custom_Theme_Dialog);
                //Code breaks on this line
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_cart_edit);
                cartProdDesc = dialog.findViewById(R.id.lblcartProdDesc);
                cartQuantity = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_quantity);
                btnDone = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_done);
                btnRemove = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_remove);

                addQuantity = dialog.findViewById(R.id.addition_action);
                minusQuantity = dialog.findViewById(R.id.minus_action);

                cartProdDesc.setText(cartItem.getProductDescription());
                cartPackSize.setText(cartItem.getPackSize());

                addQuantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        try{
                            quantity = Integer.parseInt(cartQuantity.getText().toString());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException nf) {
                            Log.e("Number Exception","Number Is Blank");
                            quantity = 0;
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            Log.e("ERROR",e.toString());
                        }
                        cartQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(++quantity));
                    }
                });

                minusQuantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        try{
                            quantity = Integer.parseInt(cartQuantity.getText().toString());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException nf) {
                            Log.e("Number Exception","Number Is Blank");
                            quantity = 0;
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            Log.e("ERROR",e.toString());
                        }

                        cartQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(--quantity));
                    }
                });

                btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if(cartQuantity.getText().toString().isEmpty() || cartQuantity.getText().toString().equals("0") || cartQuantity.getText().toString().contains("-")){
                            cartQuantity.setError("Enter a valid quantity");
                        } else {
                            newQuantity = cartQuantity.getText().toString();
                            db.updateCartItem(new CartItem(cartItem.getId(),cartItem.getProductCode(),cartItem.getBarcode(),cartItem.getNappiCode(),cartItem.getProductDescription(),cartItem.getPackSize(),newQuantity));
                            updateDataSet();
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });

                btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListner = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                                switch (which){

                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                        db.deleteCartItem(cartItem.getId());
                                        updateDataSet();
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        break;

                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to remove " + cartItem.getProductDescription()).setPositiveButton("Yes",dialogClickListner).setNegativeButton("No",dialogClickListner).show();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've got a `private Dialog dialog;` declaration further up on the `Activity` in case anyone was wondering.

The code breaks on the `dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.Custom_Theme_Dialog);` however if I comment out the `dialog.show()` at the end I have no issues, apart from the dialog not showing, but that tells me that the problem isn't with the assigning of the dialog, or am I wrong on this train of thought ?

This is a line of code in my *OrderActivity* where I'm calling the adapter, I'm sending the context from here.

```
OrderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(this,ItemList);
```

This is my constructor where I'm assigning `Context`

```
public OrderAdapter(Context context, List<CartItem> cartItemList){
    this.context = context;
    this.cartItemList = cartItemList;
}
```

Comment: Whats the `context` here ? Add code where you passing it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where that `Context` is coming from exactly, it might have already been "destroyed" by the time `onClick()` is called (well not really, because the `Dialog` is holding an implicit reference to it). In this case this is also a memory leak.

I'd suggest you to change the following:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.Custom_Theme_Dialog);
```

To this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    dialog = new Dialog(view.getContext(), R.style.Custom_Theme_Dialog);
```

This way you'll always reference the `Context` the corresponding `View` is associated with.